# A surprising inequality about a $\limsup$ for any sequence of positive numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

**Prove the following**:

> Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers. Then
> $$ \limsup \frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n+x_{n+1}}{x_n} \geq 4 \ .$$

Note:

1. Yes, $4$ is sharp: $x_n=2^n$ sequence.
2. I have already proved that
   $$ \liminf   x_n < \infty \implies \limsup \frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n+x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \infty.$$
   So, the interesting case is when $\lim x_n = \infty$.

Comment: At the very least, we have \begin{align*}\limsup\frac{x_{1}+\cdots+x_{n+1}}{x_{n}} &=1+\limsup\frac{x_{1}+\cdots+x_{n-1}}{x_{n}}+\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}} \\ &\geq2+\limsup\frac{x_{1}+\cdots+x_{n-1}}{x_{n}}\end{align*}
in the divergent case.

Comment: Let me tell you something more interesting! Assume $x_{n+1}/x_n$ converges to $L$. Then
$\lim \sup \frac{x_{1}+\cdots+x_{n+1}}{x_{n}} \geq \lim \frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}+1+\lim \frac{x_{n+1}}{‌​x_{n}} \geq 1+L+\frac{1}{L} \geq 3.$ But still a $1$ is missing!

Comment: No. Even then, remember that I assumed the convergence of the fraction, which is NOT guaranteed.

Comment: This appears also as Problem 2.4.31 in Volume 1 of Kaczor, Nowak: Problems in Mathematical Analysis. It is given on [page 47](https://books.google.sk/books?id=eoXxBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA47) with solution on [page 207](https://books.google.sk/books?id=eoXxBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA207).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Solution(as in my lecture)*
Suppose that for a positive constant $c$ and a number $N$ $$ \frac{a_1+\dots a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le c \quad \text{ for all }n \ge N $$
Let $b_n:= \sum_{i=1}^n a_n$, the inequality above is equivalent to
$$b_{n+1} \le c(b_{n}-b_{n-1}) \text{ for all }n \ge N$$
This form of the inequality is more or less more easier to deal with, but let's try it further, by letting $c_{n}$ denote $\frac{b_n}{b_{n-1}}$,then
$$c_{n+1}+\frac{c}{c_n} \le c$$
Thus $(c_n , n \ge N)$ is a sequence of bounded real numbers, thus we can choose a subsequence $(c_{n_k},k\ge 1)$ such that $$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} c_{n_k}= \underbrace{\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty } c_n}_{=:a}$$
Thus
$$c \ge \limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left(c_{n_k}+\frac{c}{c_{n_k-1}} \right)=a+\limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{c}{c_{n_k-1}} \ge a+ \frac{c}{ \limsup c_n} =a+\frac{c}{a} \ge 2\sqrt{c} $$
Or, $c$ must be bigger than $4$. This means$$\text{ if} c \ge \limsup \frac{ a_1+\dots+a_{n+1}}{a_n} \text{ then } c \ge 4$$
Hence the conclusion.
$\square$

*A small story:* This question brings back lots of memories. The first time I encounter it was when solving the famous analysis problem books by Kaczor and Nowak. A very long time ago. Then after that, in a small tutor class with gifted highschool students, I told them that it was important to find a good presentation of your problem.
And this question was *the example* I used in that class.

Comment: Very nice! There is a similar approach on AoPS (https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1247405p6417340), but your's is simpler.

Comment: Thank you, Martin

Comment: Your argument about the sequence $(c_n)$ can be generalized in the following way: Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of positive real numbers, $A, B > 0$, and $P$ a permutation of the positive integers. If $x_n + \frac{A}{x_{P_n}} \le B$ for all $n$ then $B^2 \ge 4A$. I wonder if that is of any use ...

Comment: Maybe it is useful but I don't know yet.

Comment: You mean $ \limsup \frac{1}{c_{n_k-1}} \ge \frac{1}{ \limsup c_n}$ ?

Comment: I have one doubt: How does the first inequality in the second last expression follow? Is it because of this known equality $\limsup_k \frac c{c_{n_k-1}}=c \frac 1{\liminf_k c_{n_{k-1}}}$ ?

Comment: Yes, it follows from your remark.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). I would like to add to my previous comment that the equality is valid only for positive $c_{n_{k-1}}$'s. +1

Answer (score 3):

First, assume that $\lim\sup \frac{x_{1}+\cdots+x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}=L>0$ is finite. 
Define a sequence of polynomial $\{p_{n}(x)\}$ by $p_{0}(x)=1, p_{1}(x)=x-1$ and
\begin{align}
p_{n+1}(x)=(x-1)p_{n}(x)-p_{n-1}(x)-\cdots-p_{1}(x)-p_{0}(x).\,\,(n\geq 1)
\end{align}

**Claim.** $p_{n}(L)>0$ for all $n\geq 1$.

*proof.* We have $x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n+1}\leq Lx_{n}$ for all $n\geq 1$. 
(*Edited : Actually, we only have this for sufficiently large $n$. However, this can be modified to all $n$ with a user254665's comment.*)
By induction, we will prove the following :
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}\leq \frac{p_{n}(L)}{p_{n-1}(L)}x_{n}
\end{align}
(If we prove this inequality, then claim immediately follows from $x_{n+1}, x_{n}>0$.)  Since $x_{1}+x_{2}\leq Lx_{1}$, it holds for $n=1$. If it holds for $n\leq N-1$, then 
\begin{align}
x_{N+1}&\leq (L-1)x_{N}-x_{N-1}-x_{N-2}-\cdots-x_{1} \\
&\leq \left(L-1-\frac{p_{N-2}(L)}{p_{N-1}(L)}-\frac{p_{N-2}(L)}{p_{N-1}(L)}\frac{p_{N-3}(L)}{p_{N-2}(L)}-\cdots-\frac{p_{N-2}(L)}{p_{N-1}(L)}\frac{p_{N-3}(L)}{p_{N-2}(L)}\cdots \frac{p_{0}(L)}{p_{1}(L)}\right)x_{N} \\
&=\frac{p_{N}(L)}{p_{N-1}(L)}x_{N}.
\end{align}

Now using the recurrence relation, we can prove $p_{n+1}(x)=x(p_{n}(x)-p_{n-1}(x))$ by subtracting two recurrence relations for $n$ and $n-1$. Then by using characteristic polynomial method, we get
\begin{align}
p_{n}(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-4x}+x-2}{2\sqrt{x^{2}-4x}}\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^{2}-4x}}{2}\right)^{n}+\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-4x}-x+2}{2\sqrt{x^{2}-4x}}\left(\frac{x-\sqrt{x^{2}-4x}}{2}\right)^{n}
\end{align}
for $x\neq 4$.

Now, suppose $0<L<4$. Let
\begin{align}
\frac{L+\sqrt{L^{2}-4L}}{2}=\frac{L+i\sqrt{4L-L^{2}}}{2}=\sqrt{L}e^{i\theta}
\end{align}
where $\cos \theta=\frac{\sqrt{L}}{2}<1$. By direct computation, we have
\begin{align}
p_{n}(L)=L^{n/2}\left(\cos n\theta+\frac{L-2}{\sqrt{4L-L^{2}}}\sin n\theta\right)=\frac{2L^{n/2}}{\sqrt{4L-L^{2}}} \sin (n\theta+\alpha)
\end{align}
where $\cos\alpha=\frac{L-2}{2}$. Since $0<\theta<\pi/2$, we can choose $n$ s.t. $\sin (n\theta+\alpha)<0\Rightarrow p_{n}(L)<0$. Contradiction. So we have $L\geq 4$.

---

There is an easier proof which is discovered by my friend. Let $S_{n}=x_{1}+\cdots + x_{n}$ and $t_{n}=S_{n}/S_{n+1}$. Then $0<t_{n}<1$. Suppose $\limsup\frac{x_{1}+\cdots+x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}=L<4$. Then we have
\begin{align}
\frac{x_{1}+\cdots+x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}\leq L\Leftrightarrow t_{n}\geq \frac{1}{L(1-t_{n-1})}
\end{align}
for $n\geq N$ for some $N\in \mathbb{N}$. 
If we put $f(x)=\frac{1}{L(1-x)}$, $t_{n}\geq f(t_{n-1})$. We can check that $f(x)>x$ and $t_{n}$ diverges, i.e. $t_{n}>1$ for some $n$. Contradiction.

Comment: We can show that $p_{n}(x)=\sum_{r\geq 0} (-1)^{r}\binom{n+1-r}{r}x^{n-r}$, but I think this is not helpful to prove..

Comment: Logical flaw : $\lim \sup \sum_1^{n+1}x_j/x_n =L$ with $0<L<\infty$ does NOT imply that $\sum_1^{n+1}x_j\leq Lx_n$ for all $n. $ This can be fixed as follows: Suppose that $0<L<4.$ Then  fix $m$ such that $n>m\implies \sum_1^{n+1}x_i/x_n<4. $  Now for  $ j=1,..,m $  replace $  x_j $  by $ s2^j $  where  $ s $ is small enough that  $  s2^j\leq x_j $  for $  j=1,...,m. $   Then the rest of your A works verbatim, arriving at the desired contradiction.

Comment: @user254665 Thank you very much. I'll edit it.

Comment: Now I'm not sure whether my  fix works. There may be a problem with the value of $\sum_1^m x_i/x_m . $

Comment: Nitpicking: $\limsup\frac{x_{1}+\cdots+x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}=L$ does not imply $\frac{x_{1}+\cdots+x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}\leq L$ for sufficiently large $N$. This can be salvaged of course by choosing $L$ *greater* that the limes superior, and less than $4$.

Comment: @MartinR: yes, I also had this confusion. If $x_n=\frac 1n$, then $\limsup x_n=0$ but clearly there is no such $N$ as mentioned towards the end of the answer.