# zeros of special sequence of polynomials

Tags: limits, polynomials, roots

While answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863753/a-surprising-inequality-about-a-limsup-for-any-sequence-of-positive-numbers/1863959#1863959), I make one question. Define a sequence of polynomials as
\begin{align}
p_{n}(x)=\sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor} (-1)^{r}\binom{n+1-r}{r} x^{n-r}.
\end{align}

I used Wolfram Alpha to find some properties about these polynomials (and solve the original problem, although I used the other method), I find :

**Question.**
(a) For all $n$, $p_{n}(x)$ has only real zeros.

(b) Let $\alpha_{n}$ be a largest zero of $p_{n}(x)$. Then $\alpha_{n}$ is monotone increasing and $\lim_{n\to \infty} \alpha_{n}=4$.

I tried to prove these properties without using the recurrence relation $p_{n+1}(x)=x(p_{n}(x)-p_{n-1}(x))$, but I can't. I need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest checking Theorem 2 in this paper

https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.04381

The generating function provided in this theorem correspond to the recurrence:
$H_m=-B(z)H_{m-1}-A(z)H_{m-2}$.

Your question corresponds to A(z)=z and B(z)=-z with a slight modification of the generating function: instead of having 1 in the numerator, we have 1-t:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_m(z)t^m=\frac{1-t}{1-zt+zt^2}.$

The numerator does not affect the reality of the roots since we can move to the left side and see $1/(1-t)$ as a constant multiplying $P_m$. Then, the theorem implies that the zeros of $H_m$ are real. What's more, the roots of $P_m$ lie in the interval $(0,4)$ and they are dense on that interval (For each gap in this interval we can find m such that $P_m$ has a zero in this gap).

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! While your link may provide useful information, you should strive to provide a complete explanation in your answer. Why should someone check this link?

Comment: This would be better as a comment unless you expand your post.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I updated the response.

Comment: Sorry @PeterSheldrick I think I don't understand your question. Can you say it one more time, please?

Comment: @PeterSheldrick I think what you are referring to is that the paper considers rational functions, but polynomials are rational functions

Comment: @PeterSheldrick I do not know results for the roots of a sequence of non-rational functions.

Comment: @PeterSheldrick polynomials are rational functions with denominator 1